# Prevent forwarding of systemd service logs to syslog without affecting other service logs sent to syslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, systemd, syslog

My computer runs serveral java processes as systemd services.The systemd logs get accumulated in the syslog eventually leading to low disk space . How to re-direct the logs started by systemd services towards /dev/null so that it does not accumulate in syslog.The machine is constantly running out of disk space due to this issue.However , I need to be able to use journalctl to view the systemd service logs. The possible solutions I found were :

1.To modify configurations in /etc/systemd/journald.conf by setting 
     'ForwardToSyslog=no'

2.Adding StandardOutput=null within the systemd service file itself

However the first solution completely stopped all the logs sent to syslog and solution 2 did not work.I wish to stop forwarding only the log messages from systemd services.

Answer (score 4):

The second option with StandardOutput=null should work. I think what you need is to redirect also STDERR to /dev/null, by adding StandardError=null.
Summarize - in your *.service file should be two lines:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
```

Refer SYSTEMD.EXEC(5) man page for more details.

Comment: But this solution disables the logs completely, so you can't watch them via `journalctl -u <unit> -f` anymore :/  Is there a way to keep journald but not forward to syslog?

Comment: we configured rsyslog to write logs for given service also for our specific location, after disabling this logging, `journalctl` stopped working, but we have logs available in our desired location at least

Answer (score 4):

If your service is logging to a file, the messages will not be appended to systemd syslog.

For example:

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/python-script-stdout.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/python-script-stderr.log
```

will forward all messages (stdout and stderr) only to their respective filepath.

If you want to truncate the logs on every service startup, replace `append:` with `file:`.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly on a Redhat 7.4 box, running systemd-219-42.el7_4.1.x86_64, I was unable to turn off log redirection with the `ForwardToSyslog=no` setting in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`.

I instead had success with setting [`MaxLevelSyslog=warning`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/journald.conf.5.html) which removed all the INFO and DEBUG level messages that were being forwarded to rsyslog.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure rsyslog to ignore logs from specific application:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/mydaemon.conf 
if $programname == 'mydaemon' then {
    stop
}
```

This will result in:

1. You will see systemd-generated messages about daemon being started/stopped/reloaded/etc within journal AND syslog.
2. You will see daemon's-generated messages ONLY in journal (and custom log file written directly by application, if any).

Answer (score 1):

You can still use "syslog" to redirect logs from the service to /dev/null. In your system file try:

```
[service]
SyslogIdentifier=<service-name>
StandardOutput=null
SyslogFacility=local7
```

Meanwhile, check that the syslog deamon is configured to receive logs with local7 facility. In rsyslog configuration file make sure that:

```
local7.*    /dev/null
```

journalctl should still be working.

check out the [systemd manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for more information

Comment: this worked for me, although adding more details regarding how to check the local7 facility would have been even nicer.

Comment: check if syslog daemon is configured to receive logs with the local7 facility by looking for `local7.*` in `rsyslog` configfile -- this tells syslog daemon to process all log messages with local7 facility -- `local7.*    /var/log/local7.log` means that syslog daemon is configured to process logs with the local7 facility and save them to the /var/log/local7.log file -- update the configuration file to redirect logs with the local7 facility to /dev/null `local7.* /dev/null`  -- syslog daemon discards all logs with the local7 facility including logs from systemd services -- I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

create a journald namespace and change `ForwardToSyslog` for that namespace. basically the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729452/6900

create a `nosyslog` journal namespace:

```
cd /etc/systemd
cp journald.conf journald@nosyslog.conf
$EDITOR journald@nosyslog.conf
```

set `ForwardToSyslog=no`. edit your service to

```
[Service]
LogNamespace=nosyslog
```

then

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart name-of-unit
```

docs: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/journald.conf.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `journalctl` command to limit the size of the journal. You can limit the size of the journal to a certain size, by adding the following line to `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`:

```
SystemMaxUse=10M
```

This will limit your journal to 10 MB.

Comment: Your solution does not prevent forwarding of systemd service logs to syslog